# Update markup dynamically after JS Ajax call to CodeBehind static function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using `$.ajax({...});` to send some data to my server (the aspx's CodeBehind file in c#). In order to receive this data to work with in the CodeBehind file, I have to use a static WebMethod (`[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]`). Once I work with this data, I want to either redirect them to a new page if there was a success (In my case, a successful credit card charge), otherwise, send an alert to the user that something went wrong (i.e., credit card charge randomly didn't work).

Is there a way to access/alter the current page's markup via this static WebMethod (e.g., add `<script>alert("Something went wrong")</script>`), without the ability to use asp page controls? (i.e., `this` which is the page in non-static methods in CodeBehind files)

Comment: why can't you use success and failure sections of $.ajax?

Comment: After working with the data in the code behind file, there are specific messages that may come back. I want to send those messages, which aren't really "failures" from AJAX's perspective, right?

Comment: see my updated answer, if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to use Success and Failure section of $.ajax syntax.  Please refer an example below.  I hope your web method returns string to make this work.

Sample WebMeethod

```
[ScriptMethod()]
    [WebMethod]
    public static string YourWebMethod()
    {
        String yourMessageString = String.Empty;

        //process as per your logic
       yourMessageString = "Some Message";

       return yourMessageString;
    }


$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/yourpage.aspx/yourwebmethod",
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "your data",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (message) {
                alert(message);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            },
            failure: function () {
                alert('failure');
            }
        });
```

Comment: So my question at this point is how the `error: function(xhr, status, error) {...}` works and how the message is sent from the CodeBehind file into the parameters of the `error: ...` function?

Comment: you don't need to use error in your scenario; return a String from your WebMethod; the parameter in success will capture that returned value; show it to use on success

Comment: This piece was the bit I wasn't understanding so if you can update your answer with it, that'd be most excellent. I'll give this a try and see what happens, will come back and give you the big ol green check mark if it does. Thanks!

Comment: All the logic was there in the sample; but I have still expanded the answer; not sure what else you require

Comment: All good here. Thanks so much @techspider -- was running in circles trying to do this.